# How to call method without bounding its with button?

Tags: d, tk-toolkit

I am learning [Tkd](http://code.dlang.org/packages/tkd), but in the [example](https://github.com/nomad-software/tkd/blob/master/source/example/example.d) I see how to call method (for example `openDirectoryDialog` from the button. But I want to call it's directly.

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.array;
import std.datetime;
import std.file;
import tkd.tkdapplication;


class Application : TkdApplication
{
    override protected void initInterface()
    {
        this.mainWindow.setTitle("Tkd Showcase");
    }

    void openDirectoryDialog(CommandArgs args)
    {
        auto dialog = new DirectoryDialog("Choose a directory")
            .setDirectoryMustExist(true)
            .show();
            string x = dialog.getResult();
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto app = new Application();
    app.run();
    app.openDirectoryDialog; // here is my attemped 
}
```

What's I am doing wrong? on I am getting error:
`Error: no property 'openDirectoryDialog' for type 'main.Application'

Comment: I take it's from examples... I don't know why it's done in such manner

Comment: what about `app.openDirectoryDialog();` ?

Comment: app.openDirectoryDialog(); Error: function app.Application.openDirectoryDialog (CommandArgs args) is not callable using argument types ()

Comment: Looks like you need to pass it something as 'args' then.

Comment: Try this: `CommandArgs emptyArgs; app.openDirectoryDialog(emptyArgs);`